# how to make Calling wp_mail() twice in same function with differnet subjects to different emails?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, phpmailer

how to send two emails within the same function? one email with a specific subject, the other with a different subject. have tried as below but doesn't work

```
function v_send_mail() {
    wp_mail( "firstemail@gmail.com", $subject1, $msg, $headers );
    wp_mail( "secondemail@gmail.com", $subject2, $msg, $headers );
}

echo v_send_mail();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you check this:
function v_send_mail() 
{
    for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++)
    {
        $emailId = "firstemail@gmail.com";
        $subject="My First Subject";
        if($i==1)
        {
            $emailId= "secondemail@gmail.com";
            $subject="My Second Subject";
        }
       wp_mail( $emailId, $subject, $msg, $headers );
    }
}
```